# Trouble getting logs to autorotate with logrotate

Tags: logrotate

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Gnome 3.36.8

```
$ logrotate --version
logrotate 3.14.0
```

It's been impossible to get logs to rotate automatically once they reach a size of 125M. Here's the config file saved to `/etc/logrotate.d`:

```
/home/App/Logs/*.log 
{
    missingok
    size 125M
    rotate 14
    create
}
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 0):

This solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/mnn5xd/trouble_getting_logs_to_autorotate_with_logrotate/gtz4xzq/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) took care of everything.